# set visible = false to a asp:BoundField

Tags: c#, asp.net, boundfield

i have a gridview width a boundfield:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Nome" HeaderText="Nome" SortExpression="Nome"  />
```

i want set the visible parameter of this by a condition in page_load method.

is possible?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling EnsureChildControls(), you will be able to iterate over the GridViewRows and use FindControl to pick out this field (assuming you set an ID and runat="server").